# jQuery accordion applying class to ALL panels instead of one

Tags: jquery, accordion, each

I'm trying to make a simple accordion.
For each accordion, when I click the title button, I want the panel to show.
When I click the title button of one, it opens ALL panels and not it's sibling.

This is what I have. If anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong, that would be great.

```js
(function(d,w,$) {

  $('.accordion').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.accordion-btn').click(function() {
      $('.accordion-panel').toggleClass('accordion-open');
    });
  });

})(document, window, jQuery);
```

```css
.accordion-btn {
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-panel {
  background: #eee;
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

.accordion-open {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event accordion">
  <div class="accordion-btn"><h2>Title Here</h2></div>
  <div class="accordion-panel">Text content here</div>
</div>

<div class="event accordion">
  <div class="accordion-btn"><h2>Title Here</h2></div>
  <div class="accordion-panel">Text content here</div>
</div>

<div class="event accordion">
  <div class="accordion-btn"><h2>Title Here</h2></div>
  <div class="accordion-panel">Text content here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are applying class on all panels at once. Apply only on which panel's title is clicked.

Please check this code once

```js
$(function() {
    $('.accordion-btn').click(function() {
      $('.accordion-panel').removeClass('accordion-open')
      $(this).parent('.accordion').find('.accordion-panel').toggleClass('accordion-open');
    });
});
```

```css
.accordion-btn {
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-panel {
  background: #eee;
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

.accordion-open {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event accordion">
  <div class="accordion-btn"><h2>Title Here</h2></div>
  <div class="accordion-panel">Text content here</div>
</div>

<div class="event accordion">
  <div class="accordion-btn"><h2>Title Here</h2></div>
  <div class="accordion-panel">Text content here</div>
</div>

<div class="event accordion">
  <div class="accordion-btn"><h2>Title Here</h2></div>
  <div class="accordion-panel">Text content here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to  use `this` in the line that toggles the class (here in combination with `.siblings`) to restrict that function to the sibling element of the clicked button:

```js
(function(d,w,$) {

  $('.accordion').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.accordion-btn').click(function() {
      $(this).siblings('.accordion-panel').toggleClass('accordion-open');
    });
  });

})(document, window, jQuery);
```

```css
.accordion-btn {
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-panel {
  background: #eee;
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

.accordion-open {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event accordion">
  <div class="accordion-btn"><h2>Title Here</h2></div>
  <div class="accordion-panel">Text content here</div>
</div>

<div class="event accordion">
  <div class="accordion-btn"><h2>Title Here</h2></div>
  <div class="accordion-panel">Text content here</div>
</div>

<div class="event accordion">
  <div class="accordion-btn"><h2>Title Here</h2></div>
  <div class="accordion-panel">Text content here</div>
</div>
```

(and you'll need to add a function to remove the class from all other accordion panels)